# Create a namespace-specific tagpage in DokuWiki

Tags: dokuwiki

Is there a way to list only pages that correspond to a tag within a namespace using the standard syntax of tagpage? `{{tagpage>the_tag}}` lists pages for all namespaces and this leads to duplicates with translation plugins that use namespaces for languages.
I managed to do it by customizing the url (adding `&ns=my_namespace` at the end) but I'd like to know whether this is also possible without having to paste custom links.
Especially since `[[tag:the_tag?do=showtag&tag=the_tag&ns=my_namespace|The tag]]` colors the link in red, letting people think it does not work...

I previously asked this question on the [DokuWiki discourse](https://forum.dokuwiki.org/d/18471-make-a-tagpage-namespace-specific) but got no answer...